# Visual composer add element that is similar row or section

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I use function vc_map() to add element into Visual composer. In default, the row shortcode is added to wrap out any added elements. But I want to create an element that not wrapped by row or any thing. It's similar row or section in Visual composer. Thanks for help!